# UNITY3D - Laggy mouselook on android devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, optimization, mobile, lag

I'm working on an online multiplayer fps game for android devices.

I have 12 player in my game , 6 player in one side and 6 player in other side and they kill each other.

Evrything is fine but there is an issue in my game and that is , When players are in the scene , Mouse look is laggy.

here is my code :

```
public void MyUpdate()
{
    the_time = Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
        {
            if (t.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
            {
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    delta = t.deltaPosition;
                }
                if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began || t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                    delta = -t.deltaPosition;
                    ROTX_ROTY.x += (delta.y * sensitivityX * current_speed_offset_vertical * the_time);
                    ROTX_ROTY.y -= delta.x * sensitivityY * current_speed_offset * the_time;

                    ROTX_ROTY.x = Mathf.Clamp(ROTX_ROTY.x, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

                    MyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ROTX_ROTY.y,Vector3.up);
                    x_rot_transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ROTX_ROTY.x, Vector3.right);
                }
                else if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    delta = t.deltaPosition;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody knows how can i solve this problem ?
Because this lag is only in my mouse look . Other things like walking, shooting works fine !

Is there any way to I optimize this code for mobiles?

For example I use `Quaternion.AngleAxis` instead of `Quaternion.Euler` because it's little faster... But after all this , I have lag every few second in my game.

/////////////////////
UPDATES :

I changed part of my code and change `IF` statement to `switch case` , but my problem not solved.

```
if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
                    {
                        if (t.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
                        {
                            switch (t.phase)
                    {
                        case TouchPhase.Moved:
                            delta = -t.deltaPosition;
                            ROTX_ROTY.x += (delta.y * sensitivityX * current_speed_offset_vertical * the_time);
                            ROTX_ROTY.y -= delta.x * sensitivityY * current_speed_offset * the_time;

                            ROTX_ROTY.x = Mathf.Clamp(ROTX_ROTY.x, -clampAngle, clampAngle);

                            MyTransform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ROTX_ROTY.y, Vector3.up);
                            x_rot_transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ROTX_ROTY.x, Vector3.right);
                            break;
                        default:
                            delta = t.deltaPosition;
                            break;
                    }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Where is `MyUpdate` called? And if it happens "every few seconds" it's very unlikely to be related to that script but rather e.g. the garbage collector.

Comment: And what you additional can do right now is use a `switch - case` instead of the `if-else` tags for checking the `t.phase`

Comment: @derHugo I call all of my updates in one single update in another script.

Comment: switch case and if else are same in performance @derHugo

Comment: `if-else` **allways** checks the first condition. `switch` works kind of like a dictionary and directly jumps to the correct entry -> it is not the same. However in your case this would anyway only make a minor difference.

Comment: Tank's i changed my code but the lag is steel there !. @derHugo